# Create Insights Log query from Azure cli not Log Monitor saved search

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-cli, azure-log-analytics

Using latest azure cli (2.28.1)

The creation of Kusto queries against Log Analytics with the azure cli is documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/log-analytics/workspace/saved-search?view=azure-cli-latest

using the saved-search directive.  A minor irritation is that the cli always creates legacy categories rather than non-legacy and tags sometimes are not correctly applied.

But what I can not find is how to create queries against Insights with the cli.  Combed the Microsoft docs without a hit.  Insights is a subset of Log Analytics (Monitor) but the queries are stored separately.  Alarms can target both resource groups (i.e. Insights and Log Analytics).

Comment: From the portal the HTTP post used to create a "non-legacy" query from Insights has a URL to the default query pack part of the LogAnalyticsDefaultResource group and the JSON payload matches the "Create payload" information at:

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/query-packs

The documentation even states that only way to create stuff is through the REST API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bicep (`az bicep build --file <bicep file>`) resource definitions can be defined in a template (json) then deployed with the azure cli (`az deployment group create --resource-group <name> --template-file <bicep generated template>`)

Hard part was making [parent and child resources in bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/child-resource-name-type).  Needed a parent query pack and a child queries:

```
resource querypack 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/queryPacks@2019-09-01-preview' = 
{
 name: 'DefaultQueryPack'
 location: 'northeurope'
 properties: {}
}

resource query 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/queryPacks/queries@2019-09-01-preview' = {
  parent: querypack
  name: '6967c00c-9b46-4270-bee0-5a27b8b85cef'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'BadEventsBySdcFileId'
    description: ''
    body: '<kusto query>'
    related: {
        categories: [
            'applications'
        ]
        resourceTypes: [
            'microsoft.insights/components'
        ]
    }
    tags: {}
  }
}
```

Also the query resource name has to be a GUID which is not at all clear in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.operationalinsights/querypacks/queries?tabs=bicep).  Tags are helpful to group by topic when hunting around for queries say that belong to a project domain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **az monitor app-insights query** command to run the kusto queries for application insights using Azure CLI.

We have tested in our environment Using the below cmdlets, can pull the appid for an application insights & also Total numbers requests for that particular application over a time period of 1day.

```
az monitor app-insights component show --app <app-insightsName> --resource-group <resource-Name> --query appId
az monitor app-insights query --app <appId> --analytics-query 'requests | summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 24h)' --offset 1h30m
```

Here is the reference document for more information about running [app insight analytics-queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/app-insights?view=azure-cli-latest)  using Azure CLI.

Comment: Not sure I follow and the whole component concept in unclear from the Microsoft documentation.  What you refer to is the API Access associated with Insights (i.e. appId) then running an inline query against the API.  Not really what I am efter.  Instead I want to save a query under the Logs similar to what can be done on the Monitor.